# ¿Redirección desde .htaccess a partir de una fecha?

Tags: .htaccess, redirección

Yo tengo la siguiente redirección en mi archivo `.htaccess`:

```
# Liturgia semanal
Redirect 302 /liturgia-semanal http://www.midominio.com/url-esta-semana
```

Pero me gustaría tener por adelantado varias redirecciones, sin tener que modificar cada semana el archivo `.htaccess`.

¿Cómo podría hacer para tener por ejemplo esto:

```
#Redirección actual
Redirect 302 /liturgia-semanal http://www.midominio.com/url-esta-semana
```

Y luego varias redirecciones a partir de una fecha dada:

```
#Redirección a partir de lunes de la próxima semana
Redirect 302 /liturgia-semanal http://www.midominio.com/url-proxima-semana


#Redirección a partir de lunes dentro de dos semanas
Redirect 302 /liturgia-semanal http://www.midominio.com/url-dentro-de-dos-semanas
```

Comment: Yo haría un PHP que genere el .htaccess según fecha y condiciones. Después lo llamas con un Cron.

Comment: Esto casi parecería más sencillo y manejable haciéndolo con algún lenguaje en el lado del servidor (p.e. tener una única página que redireccione adecuadamente a partir de la fecha y los valores en una base de datos). Tal y como está planteado puedes acabar con un .htaccess enrevesado y que debe cambiarse cada X tiempo.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cómo habilitar página después de una fecha estimada?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132163/127)

Answer (score 5):

Podrías usar las [variables de Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/es/expr.html#vars):

- **TIME_YEAR** El año en curso: (`e.g. 2017`)
- **TIME_MON**  El mes en curso (`eg: 01, ..., 12`)
- **TIME_DAY**  El día del mes en curso (`eg: 01, ...`)
- **TIME**  La fecha y hora en formato `YYYYMMDDhhmmss` (`eg: 20101231235959`)

### Ejemplos:

#### Apache 2.4+:

A partir de esta versión tenemos disponibles el uso de las declaraciones [`If, ElseIf y Else`](https://blogs.apache.org/httpd/entry/new_in_httpd_2_4)

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/liturgia-semanal'">

   #Redirección a partir de lunes dentro de dos semanas
  <If "%{TIME_YEAR} == 2017 && %{TIME_MON} == 12 && %{TIME_DAY} >= 25">
    Redirect 302 http://www.midominio.com/url-dentro-de-dos-semanas
  </If>

   #Redirección a partir de lunes de la próxima semana
  <If "%{TIME_YEAR} == 2017 && %{TIME_MON} == 12 && %{TIME_DAY} >= 18">
    Redirect 302 http://www.midominio.com/url-proxima-semana
  </If>

   #Redirección actual
   Redirect 302 http://www.midominio.com/url-esta-semana
</If>
```

**NOTA:** Si la `URL` de destino, posee la fecha, entonces se podría simplificar a algo como:

```
#Redirección actual
Redirect 302 /liturgia-semanal http://www.midominio.com/url-esta-semana-%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_YEAR}
```

---

#### Apache 2.0+

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # Antes de 25/12/2017
  RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} <20171225
  RewriteRule ^liturgia-semanal$ http://www.midominio.com/url-proxima-semana [L]

  # Semana después del 25/12/2017 al 01/01/2018
  RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} <20180101
  RewriteRule ^liturgia-semanal$ http://www.midominio.com/url-dentro-de-dos-semanas [L]
</IfModule>

#Redirección actual
Redirect 302 /liturgia-semanal http://www.midominio.com/url-esta-semana
```

Usando `TIME`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # Antes de 25/12/2017
  RewriteCond %{TIME} <20171225000000
  RewriteRule ^liturgia-semanal$ http://www.midominio.com/url-proxima-semana [L]

  # Semana después del 25/12/2017 al 01/01/2018
  RewriteCond %{TIME} <20180101000000
  RewriteRule ^liturgia-semanal$ http://www.midominio.com/url-dentro-de-dos-semanas [L]
</IfModule>

#Redirección actual
Redirect 302 /liturgia-semanal http://www.midominio.com/url-esta-semana
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72084/discussion-on-answer-by-marcos-redireccion-desde-htaccess-a-partir-de-una-fech).

Answer (score 0):

En una `RewriteCond` se pueden concatenar las [variables de Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/es/expr.html#vars) `%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}` para comparar la fecha:

```python
RewriteEngine On
#modificar si estamos en una subcarpeta. Ej: RewriteBase /carpeta
RewriteBase /

# Esta semana (antes de 29/1/2018)
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} <20180129
RewriteRule ^liturgia-semanal/?$ url-esta-semana [NC,R=302,L]
# Próxima semana (antes del 5/2/2018)
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} <20180205
RewriteRule ^liturgia-semanal/?$ url-proxima-semana [NC,R=302,L]
# Después (no hace falta condición si llegó acá)
RewriteRule ^liturgia-semanal/?$ url-dentro-de-dos-semanas [NC,R=302,L]
```

Esto hará que esta semana redireccione:
`http://sitio.com/liturgia-semanal` a `http://sitio.com/url-esta-semana`

que a partir del 29/1/18 redireccione:
`http://sitio.com/liturgia-semanal` a `http://sitio.com/url-proxima-semana`

y que a partir del 5/2/18 redireccione:
`http://sitio.com/liturgia-semanal` a `http://sitio.com/url-dentro-de-dos-semanas`

Si se quiere redireccionar a una URL externa, se puede usar la URL calificada. Ejemplo:
`RewriteRule ^liturgia-semanal/?$ http://otra.url/pagina [NC,R=302,L]`

Además, quizás en este caso no te interese redireccionar, sino simplemente reescribir. Es decir, que siempre se acceda a `/liturgia-semanal`, muestre esa dirección en la URL, no haya redirección, pero que se muestre el contenido de páginas diferentes según la fecha. Para eso, solamente hay que modificar el código anterior eliminando el flag `R=302`.

Subí un ejemplo a un hosting gratuito. Se pueden probar los 3 casos: [uno](http://mariano.uphero.com/125023/uno), [dos](http://mariano.uphero.com/125023/dos) y [tres](http://mariano.uphero.com/125023/tres).

Comment: Gracias Mariano. Sin embargo, sigue sin funciona: `RewriteEngine On
#modificar si estamos en una subcarpeta. Ej: RewriteBase /carpeta
RewriteBase /

# Esta semana (antes de 29/1/2018)
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} <20180129
RewriteRule ^liturgia-semanal/?$ http://bit.ly/2DsJ2ag [NC,R=302,L]
# Próxima semana (antes del 5/2/2018)
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} <20180205
RewriteRule ^liturgia-semanal/?$ http://bit.ly/2Ez1Lg9 [NC,R=302,L]
# Después (no hace falta condición si llegó acá)
RewriteRule ^liturgia-semanal/?$ http://bit.ly/2FU0t0G [NC,R=302,L]`

Comment: La URL está en el root, y las redirecciones tienen que hacerse a enlaces externos, son enlaces cortos de bytli.

Comment: creo que `mod_rewrite`  está activado. El log de apache he estado mirando y creo que no me dejan verlo, estoy en un hosting compartido y no veo archivos de log.

Comment: @A.Cedano entonces creo que es cuestión de ir depurando de menos a más. Ver si está tomando el .htaccess (con un ejemplo muy simple del estilo `DirectoryIndex otroarchivo.php`, para que en `/` no vaya al index.php sino al otro archivo, pero sólo esa línea en el .htaccess, nada más)... Luego ver si te funciona una redirección simple como `RewriteEngine On` `RewriteRule ^desde\.php$ hasta.php [R]`... Y por último ver si acepta esa misma redirección a un sitio externo.

Comment: Mariano yo tengo la redirección de Wordpress, la cual funciona: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>` Y en una API que tengo en una carpeta del dominio redirijo todo a `index.php` de esta manera: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?PATH_INFO=$1 [L,QSA]`. ...  Y  así, también funciona: `Redirect 302 /liturgia-semanal http://bit.ly/2DsJ2ag`

Comment: Sí Mariano, he quitado todo lo relativo a estas redirecciones, probando sólo con las respuestas dadas por ti y por Marcos. En otra carpeta no he probado.

Comment: @A.Cedano no me imagino qué más puede ser sin ver el error... Sólo puedo decirte que funciona en el ejemplo que subí.

Comment: No la había revisado. Escribiendo el comando `date` en `SSH` me devuelve: `Mon Jan 22 11:54:09 MST 2018`