# ¿Cómo habilitar página después de una fecha estimada?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto muy extenso muy largo pero tengo productos para presentar pero aún el proyecto de la página se esta desarrollando.

Entonces he pensado en crear un solo diseño indexado por decir la siguiente [plantilla](https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/july-2016/15-07-2016/countdown_timer_widget/web/) pero al llegar a la fecha habilitar una página para su adquisión o otro dato a mí interés.

Tengo ya realizado lo siguiente:

```js
$(function(){
    var calcNewYear = setInterval(function(){
        date_future = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() +1, 0, 1);
        date_now = new Date();

        seconds = Math.floor((date_future - (date_now))/1000);
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
        hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
        days = Math.floor(hours/24);
        
        hours = hours-(days*24);
        minutes = minutes-(days*24*60)-(hours*60);
        seconds = seconds-(days*24*60*60)-(hours*60*60)-(minutes*60);

        $("#time").text("Time until new year:\nDays: " + days + " Hours: " + hours + " Minutes: " + minutes + " Seconds: " + seconds);
    },1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Pero realizarlo de la siguiente manera no bastaría, debido que está información está a lado del cliente y esto se podría modificar o cambiar la fecha de nuestro computador.

Por decir faltan 3 días para habilitar este producto, cambio la fecha de mi computador adelantando esos 3 días y la información que no debe mostrarse aún, la información se mostraría ***corrigame si estoy equivocado***

> Entonces es posible combinar el código `javascript time` con `PHP/MYSQLI` Tomar las fecha desde una base de datos  de cuando la página se habilitará y mediante PHP 
>   envíar la fecha del servidor al código Javascript y no del cliente y al llegar a la fecha mostrar la información deseada mediante PHP.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con _evitar que el código `javascript` sea manipulado._?

Comment: @kacospro la información puede ser manipulada y también el código porque es el lado del cliente porque la duda en algo que se puede entender después de haber especificado las contras de hacerlo solo con Javascript. *Comentarios innecesarios creo yo*

Comment: @OneL nunca vamos a poder controlar lo que haga el cliente, si alguien quiere manipular tu código javascript va a encontrar la forma de hacerlo, por eso no me quedó claro que quisiste decir con _evitar que sea manipulado_

Comment: @IniDesing.com el enlace que compartiste como solución va mas enfoncado al [`Subresource integrity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) que ayuda a evitar un ataque de [`Man in the Middle`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_intermediario), mas no evita que manipulen tu código javascript con las herramientas de desarollo de un navegador, al parecer tu tampoco entendiste que es lo que quiere el OP

Comment: @kacospro Si entendí muy bien y de hecho usted también ya lo comentaste pero eso no es lo que pregunta... Y la pregunta es clara al menos para mí. Lo que el usuario SO quiere es evitar que la fecha sea modificada y como es el lado del cliente esto se puede hacer fácilmente cambiando la fecha de nuestro ordenador entonces lo que el SO quiere es hacerlo dinámico conjuntamente con PHP y MySQLi que la fecha vaya tomando del servidor y no del cliente.

Comment: No me queda claro, porque al decir _Y con ese procedimiento evitar que el código javascript sea manipulado o que se muestre información falsa al cambiar las fecha de nuestro computador._ entiendo que quiere evitar que alguien use las herramientas de desarollo para modificar su código, en este caso de nada serviría hacerlo con PHP porque si quiero modificar el código fuente de la página con las herramientas de desarollador lo puedo hacer. PD: ¿Eres de Ecuador? Si si, yo también!! Da gusto ver un paisano por acá :D

Comment: @kacospro olvidemos esos temas amigos, he editado mi pregunta con lo que deseó hacer :)

Comment: Controla la salida del contenido con php dependiendo de la fecha le hace requiere once al trozo de código php o html que quiere mostrar... Es bastante cencillo. Y no depende del cliente.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Si hay un contenido que no se quiere mostrar hasta que se cumpla cierta condición, **nunca lo dejes del lado del cliente**. Si la validación está en el cliente, no es seguro, no importa lo que hagas siempre se puede quebrar. El servidor es el que tiene que realizar esa validación, y ofrecer el contenido cuando se cumpla la condición (en este caso, pasada una fecha).

Entonces, estos son los pasos desde que un usuario solicita la página:

1. En el servidor: obtener página según fecha.

   Si es menor a la `fecha`, mostrar la `Página A`. Ir al punto 2.
   Si es mayor o igual a la `fecha`, mostrar la `Página B`. Ir al punto 3.
2. En el cliente: `Página A`.

   1. Mostrar la cuenta regresiva.
   2. Si la cuenta regresiva llega a cero, **recargar** la página.
      De esta forma, se vuelve al punto 1, donde el servidor evalúa si realmente es la fecha y entrega la página que corresponde, sin importar si el cliente tiene la fecha bien o mal.
3. En el cliente: `Página B`.

   Ve el producto nuevo y puede adquirirlo.
   No hay cuenta regresiva en el código, evitando problemas si ya es la fecha pero el usuario tiene un reloj atrasado que haría que siga mostrando la cuenta regresiva.

---

#### 1. En el servidor. Mostrar la página correcta.

Si el usuario accede a `index.php`, desde el código de ese script mostrarías el contenido de la página A (`cuentaregresiva.php`) o, si ya es la fecha, el contenido de la página B (`comprarproducto.php`).

Este sería el código en `index.php`:

```php
<?php

//Fecha a partir de la cual se muestra la Página B (podrías obtenerla de la base de datos)
$fechaLanzamiento = '2018-02-01 00:00:00';
//Zona horaria de tu país para la fecha de lanzamiento
//    (listado en http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)
$zonaHoraria = new DateTimeZone('America/Mexico_City');
//nombres de los archivos que se deben abrir
$paginaA = 'cuentaregresiva.php';
$paginaB = 'comprarproducto.php';

//Calculamos fecha y hora
$fechaHoraLanzamiento = new DateTime($fechaLanzamiento, $zonaHoraria);
$fechaHoraActual = new DateTime();

//La fecha actual es menor a la fecha de lanzamiento??
if ($fechaHoraActual < $fechaHoraLanzamiento) {
    require($paginaA);
} else {
    require($paginaB);
}
```

- No hace falta código HTML en esta página. El HTML va en las Páginas A y B.
- Asegurate de que el servidor esté en hora.

Con esto, no importa si la fecha del cliente está mal y la cuenta regresiva es incorrecta. No va a acceder a la Página B hasta que tu código en el servidor lo entregue.

#### 2. En el cliente: Página A. Actualizar cuando sea el lanzamiento.

El archivo `cuentaregresiva.php` va a tener tu código JavaScript con la cuenta regresiva.

Pero para que se actualice automáticamente la página en el momento del lanzamiento, no hace falta código JavaScript. Se puede realizar con el encabezado `Refresh`, que le indica al navegador en cuántos segundos se tiene que actualizar. Desde PHP se configura así:

```php
<?php

//Calcular cuantos segundos faltan hasta el lanzamiento
$segundosHastaLanzamiento = $fechaHoraLanzamiento->getTimestamp() - $fechaHoraActual->getTimestamp();

//Hacer que actualice la página cuando sea el lanzamiento
header("Refresh: $segundosHastaLanzamiento");
```

- Los segundos hasta el refresh los está determinando el servidor. Con esto nos evitamos cualquier cálculo de horas en JavaScript.
- Este código tiene que ir al inicio de tu archivo, y no puede haber ningún espacio, ni nada, antes de abrir el tag `<?php`, porque estamos usando un [**`header()`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php).

#### 3. En el cliente: Página B. Mostrar el producto.

En el archivo `comprarproducto.php` no hace falta código. Directamente se puede mostrar el producto y rogar que lo compren.

---

#### 4. Extras

**Asignar la `$fechaHoraLanzamiento` de PHP a una variable de JavaScript**.
En tu código JavaScript de la cuenta regresiva, estabas usando la variable `date_future`. Para asignarle el valor correcto cuando se carga el script, lo imprimimos desde PHP directamente en el código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // ...

  date_future = new Date(  <?php echo $fechaHoraLanzamiento->getTimestamp()*1000 ?>  );

  // ...
</script>
```

- El [timestamp](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.gettimestamp.php) de PHP devuelve los segundos en *UNIX time*, JavaScript espera en milisegundos, por eso multiplicamos por mil.

**Obtener la fecha del servidor.** Si aún te interesa obtener la fecha actual del servidor desde JavaScript, para sincronizar la cuenta regresiva, realizamos una llamada AJAX que nos muestre el [**encabezado `Date`**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Cabeceras_HTTP) al solicitar la página actual nuevamente (la misma en la que estamos).

```js
function horaServer() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"HEAD",
        horaCliente:new Date()
    })
    .done(obtuvoHoraServer);
}
function obtuvoHoraServer(m,t,jqXHR) {
    var horaActual = this.horaCliente,
        horaServer = new Date(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Date'));

    //Acá va el código para lo que quieras hacer con la hora del server
    console.log("Hora Cliente:", horaActual);
    console.log("Hora Server:", horaServer);
}

//y se llama con:
horaServer();
```

- No hace falta ningún código extra del lado del servidor. Está realizando una solicitud [`HEAD`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD), y obtiene el valor del header de la respuesta, por lo que funciona en cualquier página, sin que haya que hacer nada en el servidor.
- No obstante, esto no es algo recomendado para hacer continuamente.

  No está bueno que tu página esté continuamente descargando otra página (por más que sea sólo el encabezado, no el HTML). A nadie le gustan las páginas que continuamente usan la conexión a internet. Además, siempre vas a tener una demora de lo que tarde en responder tu servidor (que puede ser mucho si una conexión es muy mala).

  Si vas a usarlo, te recomendaría hacerlo sólo para verificar que la hora del cliente no está desfasada. Podrías comprobar que no haya una diferencia de más de 2 minutos por ejemplo. Es decir, sólo usar la fecha del servidor si la del cliente está muy mal. Y una vez que obtuviste la fecha del servidor, guardar esa diferencia para sumarle o restarle a la fecha del cliente, pero no seguir consultándola (bueno, quizás actualizando cada 10 minutos por ejemplo, pero no continuamente).

  Tomando el código de recién, para ver si está desfasado. Una vez que obtuvimos `horaServer`:

  ```
  //Calcular diferencia entre relojes
  var diferenciaServerCliente = horaServer - horaActual,
      cantSegundosDiferencia = Math.abs(diferenciaServerCliente / 1000);

  //Podemos ver si hay más de 2 minutos de diferencia
  if (cantSegundosDiferencia > 120) {
      //Si son más de 2 minutos, corregir tu variable date_future
      // (la de tu código original para la cuenta regresiva)
      date_future_ajustada = date_future - diferenciaServerCliente;

      // y ahora sí, usamos date_future_ajustada en el código de tu cuenta regresiva
  }
  ```

Cuando la fecha del cliente no esté desfasada, te recomiendo usar la del cliente, no la del servidor.

**¿Querés probarlo?** Subí este código a un hosting gratuito (modificale el valor del parámetro para probar diferentes fechas de lanzamiento):

http://mariano.uphero.com/132163/?fechalanzamiento=2018-02-01+00:00

**Impedir que alguien acceda directamente al producto.** La Página B (`comprarproducto.php`) no está en una URL que el usuario vaya a ver en algún  momento. Sin embargo, es recomendable que configures los permisos/reglas para que no se pueda acceder directamente (pero si se te complica, podría estar en una URL que jamás compartas con nadie -no es lo mejor pero a veces es suficiente).

**AJAX para no tener que actualizar la página.** Este mismo procedimiento que usamos en el punto 1, se puede adaptar fácilmente a una llamada AJAX cuando sea la fecha de lanzamiento. De esta forma, sería más ameno para el usuario, sólo obtendrías el contenido del nuevo producto si el servidor te lo devuelve, y se mostraría en un div de la página sin tener que actualizarla.

**Obtener la página correcta desde el .htaccess**

Esta es una alternativa al punto 1. No creo que sea lo mejor para tu caso, pero lo menciono. Si estás en un servidor Apache, podrías evitarte el código PHP para actualizar. Sólo tendrías que generar un archivo de texto con el nombre `.htaccess` (sí, el punto al inicio, sin una extensión) y colocarlo en la raíz de la carpeta en donde están la página A y B.

Por ejemplo, si se quiere acceder a `http://misitio.com/nuevoproducto`, en el archivo `nuevoproducto/.htaccess` irían estas 3 líneas:

```python
RewriteEngine On

#Reescribir de  /  a   cuentaregresiva.php si todavía no es el 1/2/18
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} <20180201
RewriteRule ^$ cuentaregresiva.php [L]

#Sino, reescribir a comprarproducto.php
RewriteRule ^$ comprarproducto.php [L]

#Nota: así funciona para "misitio.com/nuevoproducto" (sin un archivo). 
#      Si en realidad estuviese en misitio.com/nuevoproducto/detalles.php
#      hay que cambiar a "^$" en las 2 reglas por algo como:
#      RewriteRule ^detalles\.php$ comprarproducto.php [NC,L]
```

Hay otra pregunta que trata esto con más detalle: [¿Redirección desde .htaccess a partir de una fecha?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/125023/127). Sin embargo, para esta alternativa, la fecha se debe ingresar manualmente y no se puede obtener de una base de datos desde el .htaccess.

**Ah, si no había sido claro al principio...**

## Las reglas de validación sensibles siempre del lado del servidor

Comment: Fantástico el ejemplo, solo una duda aquí debe ir `cuentaregresiva.php` mi código jQuery para realizar la animación, si es así, ¿Porque? el código PHP en el, o esto `header("Refresh: $segundosHastaLanzamiento");` se actualiza solo cuando llega la fecha de lanzamiento o se va actualizar constantemente?

Comment: @OneL El código JavaScript de la cuenta regresiva es sólo si te interesa mostrarle al usuario cuánto falta en una animación. Sin embargo, ese código sería independiente de lo que hace que se actualice. La página se va a actualizar en el momento correcto, no importa qué esté mostrando tu animación...Cuando el cliente recibe la página, el servidor le está diciendo "*Actualizá en X segundos*", después podrá mostrar la animación que quiera, pero no va a ser relevante si esa animación muestra el valor real de cuánto falta.

Comment: @OneL Sólo se va a refrescar la página en el momento correcto (no continuamente).

Comment: Si amigo, solo un pequeño detalle como le pasas al código de la animación time jQuery esta variable `$fechaLanzamiento` y que el resto de la animación se encargue de animar según su valor.

Comment: @OneL agregado en "Extras".

Comment: Gracias :) funciona de maravilla +1.

Comment: Excelente! muchas gracias por tu aporte!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo con ajax

**time.php**

```
<?php
$end = new DateTime('1st January Next Year');
$diff = $end->diff(new DateTime());
echo 'Time until new year: Days: ', $diff->days, ' Hours: ', $diff->h,' Minutes: ', $diff->i, ' Seconds: ', $diff->s, PHP_EOL;
```

**index.php**

```
<div id="time"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(timestamp, 1000);
});

function timestamp() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/time.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#time').html(data);
            setTimeout(timestamp, 1000);
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Esto no evita que el usuario no pueda manipular la fecha y lograr obtener el contenido que tiene que mostrar después de la fecha.